# How to make VSCode forget about an old docker container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I ran `docker container prune`, but after attaching it to my new container, I still see the old container in the explorer pane in VSCode. And I do not see the new container in the explorer pane.

And if I try to open a new terminal (`Terminal > New Terminal`), I see:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd)
"/path/inside/my/old/container" does not exist.
```

Whenever I create a new container based on the same image (drupal:latest), VSCode tries to open the old container based on this image, even if I give the new container a different name.

VSCode also sometimes shows the error "Workspace does not exist" when I attach it to the new container.

Comment: Please post how you create the containe. Docker-compose or docker run. Could be related to volumes. Try deleting all dangling volumes.

Answer (score 0):

After attaching to the new container, I needed to do...

```
File > Open Folder
```

And then, in the Open Folder UI, I needed to edit the old path there, which still referred to the old container, and then click OK.

For example, in the new container, the path `/opt` exists, so entered that path and clicked OK.  This causes the explorer to refresh and the old container disappears and now I can access the new container. I can also open the terminal now.